# Configuring the directories that NoseTests looks into

Tags: python, nose, nosetests

I have been using nosetests to run my python tests. However, I'm a bit stuck with my directory layout, which looks like this:

```
|-- src
|   `-- <bunch of c++ files>
|-- python
|   |-- foo
|       |-- bar.py
|       `-- __init__.py
`-- tests
    |-- __init__.py
    `-- test_bar.py
```

When I run `nosetests -w tests` from the root of the codebase, nosetest is failing to add the "python" directory to the sys.path as I would like. If I rename the "python" directory to "lib", this works fine, but is a bit of a confusing directory name, I think!

On the [nose documentation](http://nose.readthedocs.org/en/latest/api/config.html) the object `nosetests.config.Config` has the following entry:

```
self.srcDirs = ('lib', 'src')
```

I think the solution to my problem would be to set this tuple to `('python')`. Ideally what I'd like to is to still run `nosetests` from the command line, but set the srcDirs configuration option to 'python'. Does nose allow this? I scanned through the help of `nosetests` and couldn't find any relevant settings. I've tried writing a configuration file `nose.cfg` that looks like this:

```
[nosetests]
srcDirs=('python')
```

and running `nosetests -c nose.cfg -w tests`, but apparently that's not a valid configuration setting. I also tried skipping `nosetests` and attempting my own runner, `mynosetests.py`:

```
import nose
nose.config.Config.srcDirs = ('python')
nose.main()
```

but apparently `nose.config.Config` isn't quite editable in that way! I'm sure this is possible, but I'm a little lost. Can anybody help? Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Figured this out! The following seems to do the trick:

```
import nose
c = nose.config.Config()
c.srcDirs = ('python')
nose.run(config=c)
```